# How to show Relative path images in angular application using headless magento

Tags: angular, magento2, angular8, headless, headless-cms

I am developing a web application using Angular8 and headless magento(used for only Rest API). Angular web app and Magento will host on a different domain

I am working on the Landing page and calling rest API which gives me HTML content as a response, After the response, I bind response HTML in angular page using ***[innerHtml]***. In HTML response having img tag with src attribute having a relative path.

This relative path image is not displaying in my angular application, Is there any workaround where i can add base image path and all my images use that base image path and relative path (basePath + Relative path)?

Comment: can you share your code and relative path that you are getting ?

Comment: Below is the image path i am geeting from rest API response:  <img alt=\"setting_icon\" src=\"skin/frontend/rwd/dispensary/build/dist/images/product.png\" />

Comment: Are you getting the image, when you are putting the above tag in HTML directly

Comment: No. Relative path is not working